# Is there a method of vectorizing the printing of elements in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have a numpy array named "a":

```
a = numpy.array([
                [[1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 33]],
                [[4, 5, 6], [44, 55, 66]],
                ])
```

I want to print the following (in this **exact** format): 
1 2 3 
11 22 33 
4 5 6 
44 55 66

To accomplish this, I wrote the following:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    a = A[i]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        a1 = a[j][0]
        a2 = a[j][1]
        a3 = a[j][2]
        print(a1, a2, a3)
```

The output is: 
1 2 3 
11 22 33 
4 5 6 
44 55 66

I would like to **vectorize** my solution (if possible) and discard the for loop.  I  understand that this problem might not benefit from vectorization.  In reality (for work-related purposes), the array "a" has 52 elements and each element contains hundreds of arrays stored inside.  I'd like to solve a basic/trivial case and move onto a more advanced, realistic case.

Also, I know that Numpy arrays were not meant to be iterated through.
I could have used Python lists to accomplish the following, but I really want to vectorize this (if possible, of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [146]: a = numpy.array([
     ...:                 [[1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 33]],
     ...:                 [[4, 5, 6], [44, 55, 66]],
     ...:                 ])
     ...: 
In [147]: a
Out[147]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [11, 22, 33]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [44, 55, 66]]])
```

A proper "vectorized" numpy output is:

```
In [148]: a.reshape(-1,3)
Out[148]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 22, 33],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [44, 55, 66]])
```

You could also convert that to a list of lists:

```
In [149]: a.reshape(-1,3).tolist()
Out[149]: [[1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 33], [4, 5, 6], [44, 55, 66]]
```

But you want a print without the standard numpy formatting (nor list formatting)

But this iteration is easy:

```
In [150]: for row in a.reshape(-1,3):
     ...:     print(*row)
     ...: 
1 2 3
11 22 33
4 5 6
44 55 66
```

Since your desired output is a print, or at least "unformatted" strings, there's no  "vectorized", i.e. whole-array, option.  You have to iterate on each line!

`np.savetxt` creates a `csv` output by iterating on rows and writing a format tuple, e.g. `f.write(fmt%tuple(row))`.

```
In [155]: np.savetxt('test', a.reshape(-1,3), fmt='%d')
In [156]: cat test
1 2 3
11 22 33
4 5 6
44 55 66
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) which maps the array with a function on an arbitrary axis. Applying it on `axis=2` to get the desired result.

Using `print` directly as the callback:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(print, 2, a)
[1 2 3]
[11 22 33]
[4 5 6]
[44 55 66]
```

Or with a lambda wrapper:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda r: print(' '.join([str(x) for x in r])), 2, a)
1 2 3
11 22 33
4 5 6
44 55 66
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` makes a double nest iteration prettier, but not faster.  It's also meant to return something useful.  Using it, or `lambda` for side effects (print) is not best python practice.  In your cases it returns an array of `None`.

Answer (score 0):

To get *that exact* output without iterating, try this:

```
print(str(a.tolist()).replace('], [', '\n').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', ''))
```